# What is the proper REST response code for a valid request data not available (yet)?

Tags: rest, api-design

Say we have an endpoint like this:

`/user/my@email.com/notification`

It returns a single notification object which is generated by the server.
When you request this URL, three situations can happen:

1. The user does not exist, in this case I return a `404`
2. The user exists, and the notification is present. In this case I return a `200` with the notification in the body
3. The user exists, no notification is present. In this case, I can return either a `404 NOT FOUND`, or a `204 NO CONTENT`.

I'm leaning towards the `204`.

`404` indicates a faulty situation, where this endpoint is actually valid, it's just that the object is not available right now, but might be available when you request again 2 seconds later.
Also, you are not the one responsible for creating the object, so you can't help the situation.

Comment: Yep, sounds about right.

Comment: Technically, responding with `204` is perfectly valid. But I would go for a `200` with an empty array in the response payload. It means the request has succeeded but there's no notifications available, that is, an empty array.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin this endpoint returns a singular object, not an array. Would you return an empty object?

Comment: In this situation, `204` seems fine. If you want to go for `200` and you are using JSON, `{}` (empty object) and `null` are valid representations.

Comment: Should `GET /users/12` return a `204` also, if there's no such user right now, but it might be available  2 seconds later? That endpoint is just as "valid" as `/notification`, isn't it?

Comment: Here's a useful [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) for choosing an appropriate HTTP Status Code

Answer (score 1):

I would argue, that you should respond with `200 OK` instead of `204 No Content`.

Here is the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) for `204`, it says:

> The 204 response allows a server to indicate that the action has been
> successfully applied to the target resource, while implying that the
> user agent does not need to traverse away from its current "document
> view" (if any).

It implies the `204` code means, that the resource did not change, or is not important for the process at hand to bother the user with. It does **not** mean (at least not explicitly) that the resource is "empty" (only, that the *response* is empty).

Responding with `404` would be objectively incorrect, since the resource exists.